# For debugging in rails console: type in routing path variable and return path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let us say I have this in my routes file:

```
resources :blogs
```

I want to see the path that is returned when I use one of the routing variables.

**Example:**

within `rails console` I would expect typing in `blogs_path` to return `"/blogs"` but it does not work that way.  Instead it errors out:

> undefined local variable or method `blogs_path' for main:Object

I am aware that I can do `rake routes` and see the routes that way, but what I am trying to do here is see what is returned when I call upon a routing path variable.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  You have to call the routing path variable on `app`

```
app.blogs_path
=> "/blogs"
```